# TypeError: Object of type 'DoesNotExist' is not JSON serializable ( Django REST Framework)

Tags: python, django, heroku, django-rest-framework

Full traceback (heroku):

```
2020-03-24T16:11:47.624938+00:00 app[web.1]: Internal Server Error: /api/register_domain_name
2020-03-24T16:11:47.624949+00:00 app[web.1]: Traceback (most recent call last):
2020-03-24T16:11:47.624950+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py", line 35, in inner
2020-03-24T16:11:47.624951+00:00 app[web.1]: response = get_response(request)
2020-03-24T16:11:47.624952+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 158, in _get_response
2020-03-24T16:11:47.624952+00:00 app[web.1]: response = self.process_exception_by_middleware(e, request)
2020-03-24T16:11:47.624953+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 156, in _get_response
2020-03-24T16:11:47.624953+00:00 app[web.1]: response = response.render()
2020-03-24T16:11:47.624953+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/template/response.py", line 106, in render
2020-03-24T16:11:47.624954+00:00 app[web.1]: self.content = self.rendered_content
2020-03-24T16:11:47.624954+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/rest_framework/response.py", line 72, in rendered_content
2020-03-24T16:11:47.624955+00:00 app[web.1]: ret = renderer.render(self.data, accepted_media_type, context)
2020-03-24T16:11:47.624955+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/rest_framework/renderers.py", line 105, in render
2020-03-24T16:11:47.624956+00:00 app[web.1]: allow_nan=not self.strict, separators=separators
2020-03-24T16:11:47.624956+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/rest_framework/utils/json.py", line 28, in dumps
2020-03-24T16:11:47.624957+00:00 app[web.1]: return json.dumps(*args, **kwargs)
2020-03-24T16:11:47.624957+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/json/__init__.py", line 238, in dumps
2020-03-24T16:11:47.624958+00:00 app[web.1]: **kw).encode(obj)
2020-03-24T16:11:47.624959+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/json/encoder.py", line 199, in encode
2020-03-24T16:11:47.624959+00:00 app[web.1]: chunks = self.iterencode(o, _one_shot=True)
2020-03-24T16:11:47.624960+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/json/encoder.py", line 257, in iterencode
2020-03-24T16:11:47.624961+00:00 app[web.1]: return _iterencode(o, 0)
2020-03-24T16:11:47.624961+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/rest_framework/utils/encoders.py", line 68, in default
2020-03-24T16:11:47.624962+00:00 app[web.1]: return super(JSONEncoder, self).default(obj)
2020-03-24T16:11:47.624962+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/json/encoder.py", line 180, in default
2020-03-24T16:11:47.624963+00:00 app[web.1]: o.__class__.__name__)
2020-03-24T16:11:47.624963+00:00 app[web.1]: TypeError: Object of type 'DoesNotExist' is not JSON serializable
```

This happens when I call an api func:

```
@api_view(['POST'])
@permission_classes((IsAuthenticated,))
@authentication_classes((TokenAuthentication,))
@ensure_csrf_cookie
@renderer_classes((JSONRenderer,))
def register_domain_name(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        data = request.POST
        address = data.get('address', False)
        tot_amt = data.get('tot_amt', False)
        blocktime = data.get('blocktime', False)
        txid = data.get('txid', False)
        try:
            user = User.objects.get(userprofile__zeal_address=address)
        except Exception as e:
            return Response({'status': 'failed', 'error': e })

        last_dri = DomainRegistrationItem.objects.filter(user=user).order_by('-request_date')[0]

        if tot_amt == last_dri.get_total_price:
            domain_name = last_domain_reg_item.domain

            domain = Domain.objects.create(name=domain_name, created_by=user)

            domain_name_order = DomainNameOrder.objects.create(
                from_address=address,
                price=tot_amt,
                blocktime=blocktime,
                txid=txid,
                domain_registration_item=last_dri,
                domain_item=domain,
                years=last_dri.years,
            )

            last_dri.purchased = True
            last_dri.save()

            return Response({'status': 'success'})
        else:
            return Response({'status': 'failed'})
```

I thought this may have something to do with me trying to .get() an object ('DoesNotExist' not serializable), but the only time that happens, I use a try/except. I searched for the error in the title and got no results. Can anyone help?

Can anyone help out? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

You are correct, the exception 'DoesNotExists' is being raised because of the get, but is correctly being handled by try/except block (event though you should avoid catching too broad exceptions, is better if you only catch the 
"DoesNotExists").

The error you are getting is because you are passing the exception ("e") in the response. The exception is not JSON serializable raising TypeError.

You might want to add just the message of the exception and not the whole object. Or you can define your own serializer (which might be an overkill for this use case).

Example to send only the text of the exception:

```
try:
    user = User.objects.get(userprofile__zeal_address=address)
except Exception as e:
    return Response({'status': 'failed', 'error': e.message })
```